# Сборка native hadoop library

Tags: map-reduce, solaris, распараллеливание, c++, linux

Как собрать native hadoop library согласно [Building Native Hadoop Libraries](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/native_libraries.html#Building+Native+Hadoop+Libraries) (я не все понял, например, у меня нет папки `build/native` и что в команде `$ ant -Dcompile.native=true <target>` является `<target>`)?

Comment: `<target>` это таргет сборки указанный в сборочном скрипте Ant, скрипт как правило называется `build.xml`

P.S. Бросай это занятие, IMHO неасилишь...

Comment: @Barmaley а что в этом скрипте указано? (если есть, то можно ссылку)

Comment: Да откуда же я знаю то! Выкачай исходники - там и должен лежать этот скрипт! Я же тебе говорю - неасилишь :)

Comment: @ivan31, очень похоже, что Вы первый здесь, кто занялся hadoop.